# White border on maximized .hta file

Tags: hta

I am making a fake BSOD from a .hta file. it is perfect except for the fact that there is a white border along the program. Im not sure what to do at this point, i cant find anything on the topic. Can anyone fix this? Here is the code:

```
<html><head><title>BSOD</title> 

<hta:application id="oBVC" 
applicationname="BSOD"  
version="1.0" 
maximizebutton="no" 
minimizebutton="no" 
sysmenu="no" 
Caption="no" 
windowstate="maximize"/> 

</head><body bgcolor="#000088" scroll="no"> 
<font face="Perfect DOS VGA 437" size="4" color="#FFFFFF"> 
<p>A problem has been detected and windows has been shutdown to prevent 
damage to your computer.</p> 

<p>DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LES_OR_EQUAL</p> 

<p>If this is the first time you've seen this stop error screen, restart 
your computer, If this screen appears again, follow these steps:</p> 

<p>Check to make sure any new hardware or software is properly installed. If 
this is a new installation, ask your hardware or software manufacturer for 
any windows updates you might need.</p> 

<p>If problems continue, disable or remove any newly installed hardware or 
software. Disable BIOS memory options such as caching or shadowing. If you 
need to use Safe Mode to remove or disable components, restart your 
computer, press F8 to select Advanced Startup Options, and then select Safe 
Mode.</p> 

<p>Technical information:</p> 

<p>*** STOP: 0x000000D1 (0x0000000C,0x00000002,0x00000000,0xF86B5A89)</p> 


<p>***       gv3.sys - Address F86B5A89 base at F86B5000, DateStamp 
3dd9919eb</p> 

<p>Beginning dump of physical memory</p> 
<p>Physical memory dump complete.</p> 
<p>Contact your system administrator or technical support group for further 
assistance.</p> 


</font> 
</body></html>
```

Comment: Set `style="margin:0;"` for `body`?

Comment: it didn't work.... :(

Comment: Try adding INNERBORDER = "no" and BORDER = "none" to the attributes at the top of your script.